# What's the process for taking over a Twitter handle from someone who has agreed to give it to you?

Tags: twitter

NOTE: this is **not** a question about how to make someone give you a name you own or to kick someone off a name they're not using.

If you already have a Twitter account, and you convince someone else with the handle you want to give it up, how can you ensure you can get it?

Is there a transfer function, or do you just bank on being ready to change your handle to it at the moment it becomes available?

If it's the latter, since you need to be ready at the right time, does the handle become available the moment the other person changes theirs, or do they run in a batch?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's the latter. Handle becomes available as soon as someone releases it from their account. So yes, you have to be ready to take-over the handle as soon as someone releases it. That's how @n's account was stolen.  You can read the story here > https://medium.com/cyber-security/24eb09e026dd

Answer (score 1):

Why not do a double password exchange?

1. Exhanger just changes password to a new one.
2. Share password with exchangee.
3. Exchangee then logs in, changes password to a new secured password.
4. Exchangee also changes the email on file, which requires password.
   Done.

Comment: Because you don't want to take over their account, just change your account to use their handle.